# AngularJS : Adding variable into a chain of promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-promise

I am learning promises and am struggling with the following.

Three functions are being run in this case.

```
//returns an search query in JSON format
filterSearch() 

  // searches Parse.com and returns an array of values
  .then(performSearch)

  // I am passing the array of values to exerciseSearch and a another value (term - string)
  .then(function(result) {
     exerciseSearch(result, term);
     })

  // The results from the search is displayed in scope. 
  .then(function(exercises) {
     $scope.allExercises = exercises;

  }, function(error) {
     console.log('error');
});
```

Comment: You probably meant `return exerciseSearch(result, term)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promise chain should always have return object from `.then` to continue the promise chain

```
//returns an search query in JSON format
filterSearch() 

  // searches Parse.com and returns an array of values
  .then(performSearch)

  //(term - string)
  .then(function(result) {
       return exerciseSearch(result, term); //exerciseSearch should return exercises from fn
     })

  // The results from the search is displayed in scope. 
  .then(function(exercises) {
     $scope.allExercises = exercises;
     return exercises;
  }, function(error) {
     console.log('error');
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that the `result` you're passing on is the one from the right search?

Comment: @Bergi you are correct..he should return the `object` which is been created in `exerciseSearch`..Thanks  for heads up..let me update an answer